# How to extract a sequence of letters followed by an @ using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract a sequence of characters from a content using regex, examples are as follows:

(It is similar to user tags in social media posts):

1.(a space in here)@Mark Twain

2. @Mark Adam Twain
3. @Mark Adam Twain @Bill Henry

I have used the following regex: `(\s)@(\w+)?\s?(\w+)?\s?(\w+)?`

The problem is it does not detect the singular substring if I type the following sequence of characters:

```
For Example: @mark @sdshdg (@mark is detected but @sdshdg is not)  
             It detects both of them when @mark twain adam @sdhgh are written in full sequence.
```

What I want is - A regular expression that can extract  `@mark twain adam @bill @henry @bill henry gates`.
The name should have an @ at the beginning and a space before @ and the name can have **upto** three words. The problem with my regex is once I have a match say, `@Paul Adams`  if it is followed by another name, say `@Brett Smith`. The second one cannot detect the space before it.

Comment: You just need optional non-capturing groups, `(\s)@(\w+)(?:\s(\w+))?(?:\s(\w+))?` Not really sure you need to capture the first whitespace, but you did not show the code you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following regex:

```
(?<=\s)(@(\w+\s?){1,3})
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/F4Ejmg/2)
Details:

- Positive Lookbehind `(?<=\s)` asserts that what immediately precedes the current position in the string is a whitespace character.
- 1st Capturing Group `(@(\w+\s?){1,3})`

  - `@` matches the character `@` literally (case sensitive).
  - 2nd Capturing Group `(\w+\s?){1,3}`

    - `\w` matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_]).
    - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy).
    - `\s` matches any whitespace character.
    - `?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy).
  - `{1,3}` Quantifier — Matches between 1 and 3 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed.

Comment: Wow, that really worked!! Thanks man! How did you figure that out? If you are a regex expert please point out some resources to learn from. 

**However, there is still a tiny thing that I need, the @symbol should be detected only after a space, with the same functionality as I am trying to create user tags as in social media posts**. I was able to achieve this with long regex but that space was creating a problem. I need that space before @.

Comment: @SAF Updated the regex to require space before @. You can start learning regex from [RegexOne](https://regexone.com).

Comment: How can this regex be modified if I also want &#160 to be considered as a space. If a literal space is not there but &#160 is present instead of it? All previous rules apply.
     (?<=\s|(?<=[&#160]))(@(\w+\s?){1,3})                                                                        is this good to go?

Comment: @SAF Use the unicode encoding of `&#160` which is `\u000A0` in the regex for matching and add it to the existing list, like this `[\u000A0\s]`, the full regex would be `(?<=[\u000A0\s])(@(\w+\s?){1,3})`.

Comment: Hi, can you help me with finding the following with regex: [[{"id":2,"value":"Sumit Sharma","title":"Sumit","avatar":null,"prefix":"@"}]]

Start with Bracket [ and End with ] bracket. In between mandatory word is "prefix": "@"
Match all within a string?